# Including Local Version of jQuery Using Webpack

Tags: javascript, jquery, webpack

So I have seen multiple examples of how to include jQuery in the global namespace using webpack. I have seen code using the ProviderPlugin, imports-loader, and even a couple of other methods.

However, my JS code is going to be running on client web pages so I do not want my version of jQuery to override theirs. Is there way to have webpack include jQuery as a local variable to my JS via noConflict?

Comment: Did you see this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/1566644

Comment: @cale_b I know how jQuery noConflict works, I want to know whether webpack supports it. All the methods I've seen for including it in the webpack bundle register `jQuery` and `$` in the global namespace.

Comment: Fair enough.  Don't know webpack or how it works, but thought that reference might help.  Good luck!

Comment: @cale_b Ok, thank you!